# Python dictionary size vs object size efficiency

Tags: python, object, dictionary, cpython

Could someone explain what happens with the **memory** behind the scenes when manipulating with `dictionary` and `objects` in the following example :

```
In [52]: class O(object):
....:         var1 = 'asdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdf'
....:         var2 = 255
....: 

In [53]: dt = {'var1': 'asdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdf', 'var2': 255}

In [55]: o = O()

In [57]: sys.getsizeof(o)
Out[57]: 64

In [58]: sys.getsizeof(dt)
Out[58]: 280
```

Next thing is weird according to above values

```
In [68]: sys.getsizeof(o.var1)
Out[68]: 64

In [69]: sys.getsizeof(o.var2)
Out[69]: 24

In [70]: sys.getsizeof(dt['var1'])
Out[70]: 64

In [71]: sys.getsizeof(dt['var2'])
Out[71]: 24
```

The values in data structures are the same size, but the difference between types makes me wonder what happens on behind the scenes?

Does the example makes `objects` more effective over `dictionaries`?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) gives you *the size of the object itself*, but that's not the whole story. An object has various *attributes* that also contribute to the overall memory footprint. For example, an instance of a class has a `__dict__`, which holds the values of its attributes:

```
>>> o = O()
>>> o.__dict__
{}
>>> sys.getsizeof(o.__dict__)
140
```

Note three interesting things:

1. This is also a dictionary - this data structure is used *a lot* under the hood in Python, and is extremely well-optimised as a result;
2. There is nothing in `o.__dict__`, because `var1` and `var2` are *class attributes*, stored on `O`, not *instance attributes*; and
3. Even though there's nothing in `o.__dict__`, it's still the same size as `dt`, because dictionaries are initialised with enough space for (IIRC) eight keys to avoid frequent resizing as you add items to them (for more information on the implementation of dictionaries, see [*"The Mighty Dictionary"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68)).

Note also that if we compare the size of the instance *plus the class* in both cases, which is a fairer comparison, the gap narrows:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(o) + sys.getsizeof(O)
484
>>> sys.getsizeof(dt) + sys.getsizeof(dict)
576
```

> Does the example makes objects more effective over dictionaries?

Not at all; for one thing, as I've shown, objects are generally implemented *using* dictionaries (there is a way to not create a `__dict__` for each instance, by defining `__slots__` of pre-defined attributes on the class, but I won't get into that here) and dictionaries are objects in themselves (although the built-in types are slightly different for reasons I won't dwell on)!

In general, don't worry about the memory details unless it becomes a problem - define a class if you need state *and* behaviour (attributes *and* methods) and use a dictionary if you only need the state.

Answer (score 1):

Simple comparison of both objects indicate that the dictionary is far more complex object than a simple class:

```
>>> dt = {}
>>> dir(dt)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__',  
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__',  
'__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__',  
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__',  
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get',  
'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem',  
'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

against:

```
>>> class O(object):
...   var1 = 'asdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdf'
...   var2 = 255
... 
>>> o = O()
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__',  
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',  
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'var1', 'var2']
```

Comment: That's a bit misleading, because `dir` shows you things that are stored on both the class and the instance